# Solr + Eclipse + Jetty + custom jsp

Tags: eclipse, jsp, solr, jetty

i wish to design a jsp page which uses solr to index and search for queries. I would like to know how to do that with eclipse, jetty, solr and jsp. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to expose Solr directly to the web. Think of it as a special kind of database that needs to be protected. So, it will be a standalone service and you ignore that it is running as part of a container (Jetty). With Solr 5, just released, this is now the official position.

So, then you design your client anyway you want in the other service and it should talk to Solr using SolrJ client.

Or you could use something like Spring Boot with Spring Data Solr, which does not use JSP, but does make it easier to build a web interface quickly and to talk to Solr using it's own client library.

Comment: How do i get solr to index the crawled corpus? And will it be indexed everytime i run the java app?

Comment: and how do i get solr to use standard analyzer to stem the words?

Comment: Please use separate questions for different issues. This way, they would be useful for other people. I would also recommend going through Solr tutorials and maybe books. It would be more efficient than asking a bunch of very basic questions randomly.